# Dart throws runtime exception when using generics in type definitions

Tags: flutter, dart

`ListItemBuilder` is defined as a function that returns `Widget` when `PageResult` and page `index` are given.

```
typedef Widget ListItemBuilder<P extends PageResult>(P pageData, int index);
```

I created `QueryPageResult` by extending `PageResult` class.

```
class QueryPageResult<T> extends PageResult {
  List<T> result;
}
```

In a `Paginator` created by me used `ListItemBuilder` as follows.

```
class Paginator<P extends PageResult> extends StatefulWidget {
   final ListItemBuilder<P> itemBuilder;
}
```

When debugging the app at runtime, it shows type of the `widget.itemBuilder` as

```
(QueryPageResult<ResolutionCase>, int) => XCardView
```

But when I try to call `widget.itemBuilder(pageData, itemIndex)` it gives me,

```
Unhandled exception:
type '(QueryPageResult<ResolutionCase>, int) => XCardView' is not a subtype of type '(PageResult, int) => Widget'
```

Why am I getting this exception at runtime?

Comment: Your question is missing the code where you instantiate Paginator. That makes it hard to figure out what is happening exactly. It looks like you have created an instance of Paginator without specifying the type argument.

Comment: Actually, you post doesn’t contain a question. Maybe the issue is that you think ListItemBuilder<T> should be a subtype of ListItemBuilder (or ListItemBuilder<PageResult>) if T is a subtype of PageResult? But that isn’t the case: ListItemBuilder is contravariant in T, because T is used for a function parameter.

Comment: @spkersten
`Paginator` is instantiated as `Paginator<QueryPageResult<ResolutionCase>>(itemBuilder: (pageResult, index) { return XCardView();});`
I think this is not required because I mentioned in the post, when debugging the app it shows runtime type of itemBuilder as `(QueryPageResult<ResolutionCase>, int) => XCardView`

Comment: What does your definition of PaginatorState and createState look like? Do they have the type argument? It would really help to have all code that is involved in your question

Comment: @spkersten Yes they have type argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works. Maybe that helps you to identify if you missing something.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Container foo(QueryPageResult<int> result, int index) => Container(color: Color(0xff00ff00));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Paginator<QueryPageResult<int>>(
      itemBuilder: foo,
      data: QueryPageResult<int>(),
    );
  }
}

class PageResult {}

class QueryPageResult<T> extends PageResult {
  List<T> result;
}

class Paginator<P extends PageResult> extends StatefulWidget {
  const Paginator({Key key, @required this.itemBuilder, @required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  final P data;
  final ListItemBuilder<P> itemBuilder;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PaginatorState<P>();
}

class PaginatorState<P extends PageResult> extends State<Paginator<P>> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.itemBuilder(widget.data, 1);
  }
}

typedef Widget ListItemBuilder<P extends PageResult>(P pageData, int index);
```

Comment: I quickly figured out it was because one generic argument was missing. You saved my day! Thanks a lot for taking time to answer this question.